# Vaadin Style Names, where to find?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin 7.6.2

Where does one find a comprehensive listing of Vaadin component style names to use with .addStyleName(String) ?  Surprisingly, this isn't simple to find on Vaadin's website or Google and I suspect is (or should be) a well documented reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the java doc for the class [com.vaadin.ui.themes.ValoTheme](https://vaadin.com/api/7.3.2/com/vaadin/ui/themes/ValoTheme.html)
there is list of the available styles.

Also see the Valo theme api https://vaadin.com/api/valo/

Also you can see the Valo theme Demo https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/

I suggest you to checkout Valo theme Demo and see the code.

Answer (score 1):

addStyleName(...) is usually used to define your own styles when using you own theme (usually based on "Valo" or the old "Base" themes).

The themes, especially Valo, come with some predifined styles. These are in form of static varialbes in the corresponding classes (e.g. Valo -> ValoTheme class) in the com.vaadin.ui.themes package.